# calling unwind segue from camera method fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

My unwind segue code is working fine. I use storyboard to wire things up. And when I run the app, all is well.

But in addition to clicking a button, I want to also do the unwinding from code. Basically I am presenting a modal that contains two buttons: **Camera**, **Gallery**. User clicks on one of the buttons to go to either get an image from the camera or from the gallery. So once the image is obtained, I no longer need the modal view. Hence, as the last step in the method `(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`, I call my unwind segue as

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  //... do work here and then
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myUnwindName" sender:self];
}
```

But when I do I get the following error

```
attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. 
self = <UITabBarController: 0x127d09b80> modalViewController = <UIImagePickerController: 0x127e2fd80>
```

I understand the problem. But I don't know how to fix it.

Basically I am not supposed to make the call "while" the camera view is still on screen (i.e. my modal is not on screen yet). But then where do I make the call? Is there such a thing as `ImagePickerDidClose` or something akin to it? I couldn't find one. So thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `imagePickerController:didFinishPicking...` method fires, this is your opportunity to dismiss the image picker controller as such:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In most cases, when we call this line of code, we're sending `nil` for the completion argument.  However, if we want to do something when this dismissal is complete (as we do here), we pass a completion block argument:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myUnwindName" sender:self];
}];
```

Comment: totally awesome!! so simple. so elegant! Thanks. check and +1. (in 6 minutes :) )

Comment: You probably want a different unwind segue JUST for this action with no animation so that the animation from dismissing the image picker transitions smoothly into the controller we're unwinding to and the view controller containing this code isn't seen for a split second. Meanwhile, an unwind from this controller when the image picker isn't being dismissed should be animated, etc.

Comment: wow! I never thought of that. I don't want to bug you too much, as you have already save me great headache, but do you know how might I accomplish that. I mean, to segue back without an animation. I don't see a setting for that.

Comment: great answer. I up voted. But how would unwind without animation work?

Comment: I'm doing exactly this, but it doesn't work in my case. I have created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364690/manual-unwind-segue-from-uiimagepickercontroller-fails-with-receiver-has-no-seg) and uploaded a code sample to Github.