# how would unwind segue without animation work after taking picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

This is a followup to [calling unwind segue from camera method fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026381/calling-unwind-segue-from-camera-method-fails/25026427?noredirect=1#comment38920479_25026427). When calling an unwind segue programmatically, how would I make it happen without animation? I am looking for a solution that works in this specific case:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  //... do work here and then
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myUnwindName" sender:self];
  }];
}
```