# Manual unwind segue from UIImagePickerController fails with 'Receiver has no segue with identifier'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I've almost finished converting a large Universal app to use Storyboards, but have one issue that is stumping me.  I have created a Scene for a custom UIImagePickerController, but I can't figure out how to unwind from it.  I know I could just dismiss the controller, but I want to use the unwind process to pass the image back to the original source view controller.  When I try to do the manual unwind, I get the following exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MyImagePickerController: 0x7facdb838000>) has no segue with identifier 'unwindPickImage''
```

I think it is interesting that the crash log shows a call to

`[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`

but if I implement that method in the MyImagePickerController class, it does not get called. Also, it is interesting that at the time of the crash, the view controller's `_storyboardSequeTemplates` private property is nil, but they are visually present in IB.

I have uploaded a [demo project](https://github.com/Whiffer/Unwind-Segue-Demo) to Github that demonstrates this error and also several unwind segue patterns that I have used successfully elsewhere in the project to communicate between view controllers. Is is possible to use a manual unwind segue from a UIImagePickerController rather than using the old delegate pattern to return the image?  If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Urgh. I wonder if it's something to do with the fact that `UIImagePickerController` extends `UINavigationController`. Also the docs do say "This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing."

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I get that.  Technically, I am subclassing it, but only as a way to package the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`  methods that perform the unwind, not to extend or modify the picker itself. Storyboards and unwind segues seem to promise that the "right thing" will happen no matter how a view controller is presented. However, in this case it doesn't seem to go all the way to eliminate the need for a device type (iPhone vs. iPad) specific solution.